# Goursat's Theorem with one point non-holomorphic and bounded condition

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Goursat's theorem:
If $\Omega$ is an open set in $\mathbb C,$ and $T\subset \Omega$ a triangle whose interior is also contained in $\Omega,$ then:
$$\int_{T}f(z)=0$$
whenever f is holomorphic in $\Omega.$
here is the prove image from Complex Analysis by Stein and Shakarchi.

[image]

[image]

[image]

There is another exercise relate to this:

If $\Omega$ is an open set in $\mathbb C,$ and $T\subset \Omega$ a triangle whose interior is also contained in $\Omega,$ Suppose $f$ is a function holomorphic in $\Omega$, except possibly at a point $w$ inside T, if $f$ is bounded near $w$, then:
$$\int_{T}f(z)=0$$
My question: what method do we use to solve the problem here and when a question of exception like this is been asked?

Comment: Since $f(z)$ is bounded near $w$ it has a removable discontinuity at $w$ .

Comment: What I was think is that f(w) can be replaced by $f(z_0)+f'(z_0)(w-z_0)+\psi(z)(w-z_0).$

Comment: I would just use the fact that $f$ can be defined to be holomorphic on a neighborhood of $T$ and so the function satisfies the conditions of the theorem you shared.

Comment: You could draw a very small triangle around $w$, then connect its vertices to the vertices of the original triangle. This gives you a few triangles not containing $w$ to which you can apply Goursat's theorem. It follows easily that the integral along the very small triangle is equal to the integral along the initial triangle. But the integral along the small triangle is very close to $0$ because $f$ is bounded.

Comment: Or you could have a small keyhole inside the triangle. The integral over all the lines of the outer triangle should go to zero, because they are in a region that does not include the point w. Over a small neighborhood of the circle, the absolute value of the integral is proportional to the radius of the small neighborhood. For a small enough neighborhood, this goes to zero, so the whole integral goes to zero.? @Gribouillis does this sound right?

Comment: @curious_analyst I don't think so. It needs to be made more rigourous. I don't see where you are proving that the integral over the outer triangle goes to zero. In the above strategy, I can inkoke Goursat's theorem to claim that some integrals vanish. What theorem can you invoke?